# Make A Regular Expression Validator Trigger Another Event

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, validation, webforms

I've been working on some ASP.Net web forms, I'm quite new to the field. I found that the simplest way for me to validate a number range such as 01 - 12 for a month input was to use a regular expression validator. This was mainly because they checked the value immediately without needing to do a postback.

So now what I would like it to do is clear the text box if the input is outside the range. Is there a way to make a regular expression validator call another method or execute some code when it is fired?
Same question goes for all validators

Also I'm writing all these webforms in C# !*

I could probably use a custom validator for this but I'd rather not. Also I don't know if custom validators will check the input immediately without needing a postback

Comment: so basically what should validate your `regular expression`. can you explain it moe ?

Comment: I want to validate an input field for a month, so I only want to accept 01-12. I've got the regex for that already. But I want the validator control to clear the input field if it finds incorrect input

Comment: can you show the code ?

Comment: Usually a _validator_ shows a message? Can it call a custom function to show a message? If so, in the function, show the message then clear the box after showing the message.

Comment: Why not just use one text box control to input a date value using regular expressions instead of separating them into different text boxes?